# Open a custom busy indicator while a main window is busy or doing some task

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My application is based on WPF.

Task is I need to show a custom busy indicator while something is working in the main window ( because the app UI will be freezed untill it complete the task). So what I particularly want is as below

```
// Code in main window
CustomBusyIndicator.ShowDialog();
//....
//..code that takes time
//....
CustomBusyIndicator.Close();
```

So I must implement a window which must be flexible to call anywhere in my main application to indicate busy.

Here two points should be kept in mind,
1. When i show CustomBusyIndicator,  in background the main window should be running it's task 
2. When i show CustomBusyIndicator, the CustomBusyIndicator should be always on top of main window, user must not be able to use the main window, if he switch to other application using Start+tab or something and again when he switch back to my application,the CustomBusyIndicator should be on top(if it is not closed).

When the task is completed I should be able call just close() method to close the CustomBusyIndicator from the main window as shown in code.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to solve

```
public async void Button1_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // get a task for the dialog, but do not await here its completion
    var dialogTask = CustomBusyIndicator.ShowDialogAsync();
    // await the completion of the lengthy operation
    await SomeLengthOperationAsync();
    // close the dialog
    CustomBusyIndicator.Close();
    // now await the completion of the dialog task
    await dialogTask;
}
```

and the extension is

```
public static class WindowExtensions
{
    public static async Task<bool?> ShowDialogAsync( this Window window )
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return window.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution but if the OP does not know about async await I would not advice him to use it. A simple rule of programming. Don't use what you don't understand. And by no means am i being negative about Rufo's solution totally not actually it is a better solution and more modern than mine. I am just considering the OP's experience on a hunch, the question says it all. I don't think he knows all that much about threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to work with async await, just move your long running logic in a backgroundworker. There are several options for making the backgroundworker communicate without problems with the main GUI thread.
Based on your question and your level of experience I think you are way over your head with async wait. But Rufo's solution is fine too.

Google is your friend, There is a lot of information about using the backgroundworker and about async await too. It will just take a bit longer to fully grasp the potential of async await. Async await is btw not a solution for everything. I ran into a situation today where I ran in a database with EF6 that simply says it does not support async operations. Works perfectly well with sql server but this was pervasive. Total dissapointment because now me too have to use a backgroundworker where my first idea was async await.

The idea behind async await, is that the gui thread is not blocked if you are doing a long running task. It is more like a waitpoint where it will continue if that long operation is finished.

Other options are to use RX, but that difficulty level increases again.

Use the backgroundworker and you are fine, and your gui is never blocked. You can even cancel the work of the backgroundworker. Excellent solution for you.

Comment: When you can use a backgroundworker you can make it async/awaitable as well with much more clean use from the calling site.

Comment: yes rufo, but my point is that the OP does very likely not know very much about async await. And as I said you should not use something you don't understand. I am only trying to lower the difficulty level. But if the OP thinks he is up for async await, by all means he should use that. It would be my first choice too.